# Is there a way to make this a selected item when defining the ListItem in C#?

Tags: c#, listitem

I've created this DropDownList in C# and I want the first item to be selected, but when I try what I'm doing below it says that a bool cannot be moved to a string.

```
DropDownList ddlAisleType = new DropDownList();
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Fresh", "1").Selected = true);
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Frozen", "2"));
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Dry", "3"));
dlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Dairy", "4"));
```

Found the answer myself hope this helps someone :)

```
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Fresh", "1", true));
```

Comment: `.Selected = true`??

Comment: try this ddlAusleType.SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: thanks, was trying to be fancy and do it on one line :)

Comment: `new ListItem("Fresh", "1").Selected = true` returns `bool`. So you're adding a bool instead of a `ListItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Fresh", "1").Selected = true);
```

with

```
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "Fresh", Value = "1", Selected = true });
```

if you want to solve it inline.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `new ListItem("Fresh", "1").Selected = true` it doesn't return anything let alone a ListItem that `Add` is expecting.

Try this instead

```
DropDownList ddlAisleType = new DropDownList();
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Fresh", "1")));
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Frozen", "2"));
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Dry", "3"));
dlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Dairy", "4"));

dlAisleType.Items.First().Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use FindByValue and FindByText function.i have add sample code so try it.

```
DropDownList ddlAisleType = new DropDownList();
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Fresh", "1").Selected = true);
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Frozen", "2"));
ddlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Dry", "3"));
dlAisleType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Dairy", "4"));
```

Select by Value:

```
dlAisleType.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;
```

Select by Text(Item Name):

```
dlAisleType.Items.FindByText("Fresh").Selected = true;
```